# Can gcc check printf formats when using gettext?

Tags: c, gcc, gettext

Gcc can check that printf arguments match the format given. But that only works when the argument to printf is liternal. And obviously so, gcc needs to know the format.

Now when the code is localized, it's usually the format that needs localizing. So it is passed through gettext, but than it isn't literal anymore and gcc can't check that the arguments match.

Is there some way to tell gcc to assume the `gettext` function returns it's argument for purpose of the check?

Of course I could do a separate build with disabled localization to check, but I would like to know whether there is an option to do it during the main compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds like what gcc's [`format_arg`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bformat_005farg_007d-function-attribute-2627) attribute is designed to do:

> The `format_arg` attribute specifies that a function takes a format string for a `printf`, `scanf`, `strftime` or `strfmon` style function and modifies it (for example, to translate it into another language), so the result can be passed to a `printf`, `scanf`, `strftime` or `strfmon` style function (with the remaining arguments to the format function the same as they would have been for the unmodified string).

Not sure why gettext doesn't use this, if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was missing. I think gettext actually does use it, but I am using different implementation of similar mechanism which does not.